# How do I find out if I have SATA 2 or SATA 3?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, sata, dell-inspiron

I need to upgrade a Dell Inspiron 5520 mid 12 laptop with a Samsung 850 pro SSD.

How do I check whether my laptop with a 3rd gen i7 processor has SATA 2 or SATA 3?

Comment: Have you checked your laptop's specification sheet?

Comment: they have only mentioned that the interface is sata and not the verion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your CPU is i5 I can confirm that it can it can support Sata 3. Depends on the usage the ram may be important but generally 4Gb are enough (make sure you have 64bit Windows for more than 4Gb). I would suggest you not spend a lot of money on the SSD as you wont notice big difference between 850 and 840 on your device.